# Which pair of functions satisfy f(N) ∼ g(N)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

a. f(N) = N and g(N) = N + N2

b. f(N) = 2N and  g(N) = √N

c. f(N) = NlogN + N and g(N) = 2NlogN + N

d. f(N) = 2√N + N and g(N) = √N + N

What is the best way of calculating these functions, I have tried putting values into them, but some of them are very close in values and I am not sure which one to pick.

Comment: Show what you have done and what you *think* the answers are.

Comment: What is the definition of ~ you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate f(N)/g(N) in the limit N➡Infinity.

If f(N)/g(N) approaches a positive constant  in the limit N➡Infinity, then f(N) ~  g(N).

Comment: Specifically, [the constant is **1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#As_a_relational_operator).